# PHP 5.4RC2 and Memcached?

Tags: php, memcached

Has anyone had any luck setting up the Memcached client libraries on PHP 5.4RC2?

I have the Memcached daemon installed just fine, and can install various versions of libmemcached, but every time I try to install pecl-memcached or what-have-you, I get just so many make errors.

Am I too far ahead of the curve here?  Has nobody gotten Memcached working yet for PHP 5.4?  Google has been no help so far.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Depends on what version of libmemcached I have installed and what version of pecl-memcached I'm trying to install, and there's so many combinations.

Sadly, I don't have them handy.  But the latest round have been tons of uncleclared things, like "'MEMCACHED_BUFFERED' undeclared" and such.

Comment: If you upgraded from a pre 5 version, you might just be seeing the warnings that are new in php 5. Try setting your error level a bit differently, or even (just for testing!) to `0`.

Comment: This question is rather vague... Short of saying yes or no, no one can really help you that much, maybe a gist of your errors and/or some enviroment info could help

Comment: libmemcached 0.31 + php 5.40rc2 + pecl memcache 3.0.6 works for me. If you have it running on previous php versions you should fill bug report at bugs.php.net including complete install log.

Comment: @JamesButler - I'm mainly looking for answers like dev-null-dweller's.  "I've done this and it worked".  I'm going to go and give that a try and see if it works.

Comment: @DanHulton I think it's only fair to offer a little if you want something in return. Adding some more info to your question will hopefully help other people later when/if they have similar problems and find this question.

Comment: RC2 is a bit dated. Maybe you could try with the latest (RC6 atm)?

Comment: I have similar problems with PHP 5.4.0RC6 and libmemcached 1.0.2 installed on Ubuntu 11.10. `sudo pecl install memcached` outputs the following: http://pastebin.com/fysQ02Lc

Comment: I just found this mailing-list entry. May that helps someone ...
http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg979820.html
He tried to compile php-memcached v1.0.2-2 against PHP 5.4 (not saying which RC).